# Anchor doesn't work with Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, hyperlink

- I use Laravel.

  - I created a div with an id="myanchor" at the bottom of the page.
  - I created a link pointing to that anchor.
  - I click on the link and what It redirect the page to

> mywebsite.com/play/score/#/myanchore

- Instead of that

> mywebsite.com/play/score/#myanchore

Anyone for a solution?

**Update:**

Ok So you need more information but I don't think I can bring you more information.
I think It's server side problem to Laravel but I don't know why and how. I'm certainly not the only one with this problem

```
<a href="#myanchor">click</a>
<div id="myanchor">Hello world</div>
```

Comment: We're going to need more information to diagnose this. Some sample code would be good - preferably the smallest piece of code you can make which reproduces the problem.

Comment: agree.. what does your link url look like?

Comment: I edit my post. But I don't think its more helpful

Comment: You say laravel and you post client side code? How is that going to hel?

Comment: I said that Laravel could have some function spliting the url..
In fact I don't why when I click on my link it redirect to the url.
It shouldn't happen.. it should concatenate the #myanchor to my url that's all.

Comment: ` I think It's server side problem to Laravel` where is the server side code ? An anchor has nothing to do with server.

Comment: Can you open the source code of your page and **confirm** that the anchor still looks as you expect it to: `<a href="#myanchor">click</a>`.

Comment: @WereWolf An anchor has nothing to do with the server, but the way Laravel is routing it may.  I think the OP was hoping for a common problem that would be recognized, otherwise we'd need to see his `routes.php`, possibly the `.htaccess`, perhaps the `httpd.conf` file, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Where and how do you create the link? I put the link on the view and this works successfully.

This link `<a href="#myanchor">click</a>`

Go to my div with id="myanchor": `<div id="myanchor">Hello world</div>`

In other words goes to -> `site.com/currentpath/#myanchore`

Comment: Hi,
I put the link like you did.
But for me when I click it redirect to site.com/currentpath/#/myanchore
As if the "#" was part of my routes.